# Regex to group numbers into a separate group

Tags: regex

I have a string like below,

`[20200102 INFO] Test app: Stats [str1: 100.00, str2: 200, str3: 300]`

I have to group in such a way that, the str1 has to be in one group, str2 has to be in one group and str3 has to be in 3rd group. And the numbers have to be space separated and present in one group that is, "100.00 200 300"

When i use the below regex, each of them goes to a different group and I get 6 groups.

`(str1):\s*(.+),\s*(str2):\s*(.+),\s*(str3):\s(.+)`

Can someone point me out the right usage of regex here.

Comment: So, you may remove extra groups you do not need, `str1:\s*(\d[\d.]*),\s*str2:\s*(\d[\d.]*),\s*str3:\s(\d[\d.]*)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/NN73ST/1).

Comment: I want str1, str2, str3 to be in separate groups and all the numbers to be in one group

Comment: You can't capture disjoint pieces of text into a single group. You need to post-process the match with a bit of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try illustration `.*\[(str1):\s*(.*?),\s*(str2):\s*(.*?),\s*(str3):\s(.*?)\].*`
Replace `[$1, $3, $5] , [$2, $4, $6]`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/ksgT4U/1)